# How to handle different header file location on different Linux distributions?

Tags: c++, linux, c-preprocessor

In my code I use a header file which unfortunately has a different location under different Linux distributions.

In my case it is fitsio.h from cfitsio which is located here in OpenSUSE 12.1:

```
#include <cfitsio/fitsio.h>
```

and here in Arch Linux:

```
#include <fitsio.h>
```

I guess I can use some preprocessor directives to create a switch. I can use this to test if I am on Linux or Windows, etc. but I have no clue what I can use to test whether I am on Arch Linux or not.

Or is there another way/strategy to handle this case?

Comment: I haven't worked on any large projects, but when doing projects with Linux+Mac/Windows I always end up with preprocessor directives.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keep the simpler include

```
#include <fitsio.h>
```

Then, under additional include directories, list paths to directories containing this header both for SUSE and for Arch:

```
/path/to/header/cfitsio
/path/to/header
```

Even if the former is nonexistent on Arch, it won't lead to any problems during compilation.

Comment: The main problem with this method is that it **will** lead to problems on bigger builds. In particular, it will lead to slow compiles as file lookups fail. This however can often be addressed by conditionally setting those paths in the makefile. The idea here is that you resolve the problem once per makefile, in a single place, instead of in every source file.

Answer (score 2):

Some libraries come with a `[libraryname]-config` program that outputs the correct compiler flags to be using when compiling against that library on the current platform.

For example, `libncurses`' `ncursesw5-config --cflags --libs` produces this on [Arch](https://www.archlinux.org/):

```
-L/usr/lib -lncursesw
```

and this on [Debian](https://www.debian.org/):

```
-I/usr/include/ncursesw
-lncursesw -ltinfo
```

Having `#include <curses.h>` in the C code is then sufficient, and will compile correctly in both distributions.